# Is there a version of the PyDev debugger that supports Python 3.4 in LiClipse?

Tags: debugging, ironpython, pydev, liclipse

I want to use IronPython 3.4 as my project interpreter in the latest version of LiClipse.
The program runs fine but there is an error when trying to debug it.

I tried to run the debugger on my program as an IronPython run.
A runtime error comes up and says that "the PyDev.debugger requires Python 3.6 onwards to be run".
I'm wondering if there a version of PyDev that supports Python 3.4.